# How to check if location is changed and controller loaded

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I'm trying to write a unit test for a controller that does a POST then changes page. How can I check if a path is loaded and the controller for that path is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check that the controller associated to a given path is loaded. That wouldn't be a unit test anymore, but an end-to-end test. The responsibility of the controller under test is to change the location, and that's all your unit test should be concerned about.

To test that the location has changed, spy on its method:

```
spyOn($location, 'url');
theController.doSomething();
// TODO check the POST request, flush the $httpBackend, etc.
expect($location.url).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/the/expected/new/url');
```